# Stackable badges

Tags: paper-mario

In paper Mario What badges can be stacked with themselves to have double the effect?

An example can be if I use 2 happy heart badges will I have it's effect twice as often?

Please state witch will have 2x the effect and witch won't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All badges that can be found multiple times have their effect applied once for each copy you have equipped.

- Damage Dodge (2)
- Deep Focus (3)
- Flower Saver (2)
- FP Plus (3)
- Happy Flower (2)
- Happy Heart (2)
- HP Plus (3)
- Power Plus (2)